# Product of convolutions

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

I am a physicist working on a micromechanics problem and have run into the following mathematical issue:

I need to find the Fourier transform of the derivative of the squared convolution, i.e.: 
$$ \mathcal{F} \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[f(x) *g(x)\right]^2 \right\} $$

My simple approach was to expand the square and use the chain rule:

$$ \mathcal{F} \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[f(x)*g(x) \cdot  f(x)*g(x)\right] \right\} = \mathcal{F} \left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x)*g(x)] \cdot  f(x)*g(x) + f(x)*g(x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x)*g(x)]\right\}$$

Then we can move the derivative into the convolution:
$$2 \mathcal{F} \left\{[f'(x)*g(x)] \cdot [f(x)*g(x)]\right\}$$

The partial derivative is now effectively out of the picture, but this where I get stuck - is there a way to eliminate or reduce the number of Fourier transforms I need to do in order to solve (read: compute) this?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Hugh

Comment: If everything converges $\mathcal{F} \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[f(x) *g(x)\right]^2 \right\} = i \omega (\hat{f} \hat{g}\ast \hat{f} \hat{g})= 2i \omega\hat{f} \hat{g}\ast \hat{f} \hat{g}$

Comment: What is this witchcraft?! Is it a known proof or theorem?

What about the more general case of products with convolutions, i.e.: $$\mathcal{F} \left\{  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\{[f(x) * g(x)] \cdot h(x)\} \right\}$$

Comment: From the integral definition, integration by parts gives $\mathcal{F}[u'] = i\omega \hat{u}$, a change of variable gives $\mathcal{F}[u \ast v] = \hat{u}  \hat{v}$. From the Fourier inversion theorem $u v = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\hat{u}  \ast \hat{v}]$ and $\mathcal{F}[uv] =\hat{u}  \ast \hat{v}$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: Argh! So simple! Thanks so much!